# How i can solve query like that

Tags: sql-server

I have one problem in sql server.I have some records like

```
PKId EquipmentID StudentId      Issueddate                  Returneddate
1        116     230            2014-01-14 17:14:58.940     2014-01-18 14:12:038.876
2        116     237            2014-01-14 17:14:58.940     NULL
3        117     400            2014-01-14 17:14:58.940     2014-01-18 14:12:038.876
```

Here EquipmentID and StudentId are the foreign key.We need to write a query which gives us data based on Returneddate.We need to check condition one like in first row equipmentid is 116 and it's assigned to studentId 230 where Returneddate is not null means for now this 116 equipment is free means it is unassiged but in the next line same equipment is assigned to student 237 and hiis returneddate is NULL means this equipment is assined to someone and in last case equipmentid 117 assigned to studentid 400 and it's returneddate is not null means it is available.

So we need to show only those records which is available.If i took this case as example then it will give me

`3   117  400  2014-01-14 17:14:58.940 2014-01-18 14:12:038.876` row as a output.

I Tried:

```
select * from Equipment where (EquipmentID not in (select EquipmentID
from PEquip where Returneddate is null))
```

Please help me.

Hope you understand.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Which is it?

Comment: show the query you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got it right you need `EquipmentID` for which there are no rows with NULL `Returneddate`.

```
SELECT * FROM T as T1 
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T 
                            WHERE EquipmentID=T1.EquipmentID
                                  AND Returneddate IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from theTable t1 where returneddate = 
    (select max Issueddate from theTable t2 where t1.EquipmentId = t2.EquipmentId)
and returneddate is not NULL;
```

Comment: I think first record will give as an output as per your query what you say

Answer (score 1):

```
 select * from EuipmentDetails where EquipmentID 
   not in (select EquipmentID  from EuipmentDetails where Returneddate is NULL )
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the order of `PkId` is consistent with the chronology of the data, I'd go with

```
SELECT PKId, EquipmentID, StudentId, Issueddate, Returneddate 
FROM Equipment E 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(PKId) AS PKId FROM Equipment GROUP BY EquipmentId) AS T
ON E.PKId = T.PKId
WHERE E.ReturnedDate IS NOT NULL
```

Logic: select the latest entry for each `EquipmentId`, **IF** the latest entry has ReturnedDate not null.